# In what way is Magneto "offering a home" to Xavier?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, magneto, x-men-dark-phoenix

In the final scene of *X-Men: Dark Phoenix* we see Magneto sit down for a conversation with Xavier. He begins by asking Xavier how retirement is treating him and later says the following:

> MAGNETO: A long time ago, you saved my life. Then you offered me a home. I'd like to do the same for you.

This line confuses me a bit. Based on Magneto's comment earlier, Xavier is apparently retired from actively teaching at the mutant school. Retired does not mean homeless. Why would Xavier be in need of a new home? In what way is Magneto "offering a home" to Xavier?

Comment: Surely that Xavier should come and join his community of mutants living in the woods?

Comment: @Valorum is Magneto saying "come to our village and be our neighbor" or is he saying "come live with me in my house"? And why is either needed? Are we to understand that Xavier has been kicked out of the school?

Answer (score 3):

I believe Magneto was offering Xavier to settle down in Genosha(The [island](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/Genosha#X-Men:_Dark_Phoenix) he was using as a sanctuary for mutants). I'd assume he means home as more of a "family" point of view. As for the need, he could be referring to the loss of friends/students he has suffered, which would include:

- Mystique
- Jean Grey

Also, Xavier did retire from his role as headmaster, he gave the position to Beast according to [Wiki](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Dark_Phoenix#Plot).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. While I agree with this answer, it'd be a lot more persuasive if you edited it to expand on your reasoning, and include any relevant evidence, such as specific quotes.

Comment: For a moment Magneto almost sounded like he's asking Xavier to come live _with_ him (in the same house). Also I figured Xavier could still live in the mansion even if he wasn't teaching anymore - unless we're saying they other kicked him out, is that what we're saying?

Comment: He surely can, but I figured Magneto meant the mansion wouldn't be homely to him after the passing of Mystique and Jean. For me, it felt like home wasn't just a place to live, more like the surroundings the place has, Magneto was most likely referring to that.